# Android PrintManager good preview, fails to print/make pdf

Tags: android, pdf, printing

My app is creating a PDF with the following code. When executed, it brings up the android print manager just fine (where you can select cloud print, save to PDF, or select a printer). In this window, there is a correct preview of the page. However, when clicking the button to save, the created file is not a valid PDF (0 kb). No error messages.

Sorry for the long code. I've cut out some, but not sure what is relevant. I'm guessing the problem is in `onLayout` or `onWrite` of the adapter class.

```
public class PDFMaker {

@TargetApi(19)
public void printDocument(Context context) {
    lesson = WelcomeActivity.selectedLesson;
    Typeface textType = textPaint.getTypeface();

    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    String jobName = context.getString(R.string.app_name) +
            " Document";

    printManager.print(jobName, new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(context),
            null);
}

@TargetApi(19)
public class MyPrintDocumentAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {
    Context context;
    private int pageHeight;
    private int pageWidth;
    public PdfDocument myPdfDocument;
    int startIndex = 0;
    Paint boxPaint = new Paint();
    boolean hasExtraProcess = false;
    StaticLayout extraProcessLayout;
    int extraProcessHeight = 0;

    public MyPrintDocumentAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        boxPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        boxPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes,
                         PrintAttributes newAttributes,
                         CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                         LayoutResultCallback callback,
                         Bundle metadata) {
        myPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, newAttributes);

        pageHeight =
                792;
        pageWidth =
                612;

        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            callback.onLayoutCancelled();
            return;
        }
        PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo
                .Builder(lesson.getField("title") + ".pdf")
                .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT);

        PrintDocumentInfo info = builder.build();
        callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWrite(final PageRange[] pageRanges,
                        final ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
                        final CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                        final WriteResultCallback callback) {

        int pageNumber = 1;
        while (startIndex < boxes.length) {
            PageInfo newPage = new PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth,
                    pageHeight, pageNumber).create();

            PdfDocument.Page page =
                    myPdfDocument.startPage(newPage);

            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                callback.onWriteCancelled();
                myPdfDocument.close();
                myPdfDocument = null;
                return;
            }
            drawPage(page, pageNumber);
            myPdfDocument.finishPage(page);
            pageNumber++;
        }

        try {
            myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(
                    destination.getFileDescriptor()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            callback.onWriteFailed(e.toString());
            return;
        } finally {
            myPdfDocument.close();
            myPdfDocument = null;
        }

        callback.onWriteFinished(pageRanges);
    }

    private void drawPage(PdfDocument.Page page,
                          int pagenumber) {
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        TextPaint headerPaint = new TextPaint();
        headerPaint.setTextSize(14);
        StaticLayout pageNumLayout = new StaticLayout(String.valueOf(pagenumber), headerPaint, printWidth/2, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE, 1, 0, false);
        canvas.translate(26, 18);
        if (pagenumber == 1) {
            canvas.translate(printWidth/2, 0);
            pageNumLayout.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            StaticLayout header = new StaticLayout(lesson.getField("title") + " Lesson by " + lesson.getField("authorName"), headerPaint, printWidth/2, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, false);
            header.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(printWidth/2, 0);
            pageNumLayout.draw(canvas);
        }
        canvas.translate(-(printWidth / 2), pageNumLayout.getHeight() + 8);

        int pageFillHeight = 8;
        if (hasExtraProcess) {
            drawExtraProcessBox(canvas);
            if(hasExtraProcess) {
                return;
            }
            pageFillHeight += extraProcessHeight + 8;
            startIndex = 6;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            if (i >= startIndex) {
                int viewHeight = boxes[i];
                if ((viewHeight + pageFillHeight + 8) < printHeight) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            drawTopBox(canvas);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            drawObjectivesBox(canvas);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            drawStandardsBox(canvas);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            drawRepBox(canvas);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            drawMediaBox(canvas);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            drawProcessBox(canvas);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            drawAssessmentBox(canvas);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            drawCommentBox(canvas);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    pageFillHeight += viewHeight + 8;
                    if (i == boxes.length - 1) {
                        startIndex = i + 1;
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (i == 5) {
                        breakProcessBox(canvas, printHeight - pageFillHeight);
                    }
                    startIndex = i;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void drawTopBox(Canvas canvas) {
        titleLayout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(0, titleLayout.getHeight() + 8);
        authorLayout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(0, authorLayout.getHeight() + 8);
        gradeLayout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(printWidth / 2, 0);
        dateLayout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(-(printWidth / 2), gradeLayout.getHeight() + 8);
    }

    private void drawObjectivesBox(Canvas canvas) {
        //Objectives
        int totalHeight = 8;
        canvas.translate(0, 8);
        primaryObjectiveLabel.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(100, 0);
        element1Layout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(150, 0);
        objective1Layout.draw(canvas);
        if (primaryObjectiveLabel.getHeight() > objective1Layout.getHeight()) {
            canvas.translate(-250, primaryObjectiveLabel.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += primaryObjectiveLabel.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(-250, objective1Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += objective1Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        secondaryObjectiveLabel.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(100, 0);
        element2Layout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(150, 0);
        objective2Layout.draw(canvas);
        if (objective2Layout.getHeight() > element2Layout.getHeight()) {
            canvas.translate(-150, objective2Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += objective2Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(-150, element2Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += element2Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        element3Layout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(150, 0);
        objective3Layout.draw(canvas);
        if (objective3Layout.getHeight() > element3Layout.getHeight()) {
            canvas.translate(-250, objective3Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += objective3Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(-250, element3Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += element3Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        canvas.translate(-8, -totalHeight);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, printWidth + 16, totalHeight, boxPaint);
        canvas.translate(8, totalHeight + 8);
    }

    private void drawStandardsBox(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.translate(0, 8);
        int totalHeight = 8;
        primaryCoreLabel.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(100, 0);
        coreProc1Layout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(150, 0);
        coreStand1Layout.draw(canvas);
        if(primaryCoreLabel.getHeight() > coreStand1Layout.getHeight()) {
            canvas.translate(-250, primaryCoreLabel.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += primaryCoreLabel.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(-250, coreStand1Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += coreStand1Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        secondaryCoreLabel.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(100, 0);
        coreProc2Layout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(150, 0);
        coreStand2Layout.draw(canvas);
        if (coreProc2Layout.getHeight() > coreStand2Layout.getHeight()) {
            canvas.translate(-150, coreProc2Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += coreProc2Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(-150, coreStand2Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += coreStand2Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        coreProc3Layout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(150, 0);
        coreStand3Layout.draw(canvas);
        if (coreProc3Layout.getHeight() > coreStand3Layout.getHeight()) {
            canvas.translate(-250, coreProc3Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += coreProc3Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(-250, coreStand3Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += coreStand3Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        canvas.translate(-8, -totalHeight);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, printWidth + 16, totalHeight, boxPaint);
        canvas.translate(8, totalHeight + 8);
    }

    private void drawRepBox(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.translate(0, 8);
        int totalHeight = 8;
        repLabel.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(100, 0);
        rep1Layout.draw(canvas);
        if (repLabel.getHeight() > rep1Layout.getHeight()) {
            canvas.translate(0, repLabel.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += repLabel.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(0, rep1Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += rep1Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        if (!lesson.getField("repertoire2").equals("")) {
            rep2Layout.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(0, rep2Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += rep2Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        if (!lesson.getField("repertoire3").equals("")) {
            rep3Layout.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(-100, rep3Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += rep3Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(-100, 0);
        }
        if (scoreBMP != null) {

            canvas.drawBitmap(scoreBMP, 0, 0, new Paint());
            canvas.translate(0, scoreBMP.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += scoreBMP.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        canvas.translate(-8, -totalHeight);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, printWidth + 16, totalHeight, boxPaint);
        canvas.translate(8, totalHeight + 8);
    }

    private void drawMediaBox(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.translate(0, 8);
        int totalHeight = 8;
        mediaLabel.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(100, 0);
        m1Layout.draw(canvas);
        if (mediaLabel.getHeight() > m1Layout.getHeight()) {
            canvas.translate(0, mediaLabel.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += mediaLabel.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(0, m1Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += m1Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        if (!lesson.getField("media2").equals("")) {
            m2Layout.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(0, m2Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += m2Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        if (!lesson.getField("media3").equals("")) {
            m3Layout.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(0, m3Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += m3Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        if (!lesson.getField("media4").equals("")) {
            m4Layout.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(0, m4Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += m4Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        if (!lesson.getField("media5").equals("")) {
            m5Layout.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(0, m5Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += m5Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        if (!lesson.getField("media6").equals("")) {
            m6Layout.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(-100, m6Layout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += m6Layout.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(-100, 0);
        }
        canvas.translate(-8, -totalHeight);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, printWidth + 16, totalHeight, boxPaint);
        canvas.translate(8, totalHeight + 8);
    }

    private void drawProcessBox(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.translate(0, 8);
        int totalHeight = 8;
        processLabel.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(100, 0);
        processLayout.draw(canvas);
        if (processLabel.getHeight() > processLayout.getHeight()) {
            canvas.translate(-100, processLabel.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += processLabel.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(-100, processLayout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += processLayout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        canvas.translate(-8, -totalHeight);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, printWidth + 16, totalHeight, boxPaint);
        canvas.translate(8, totalHeight + 8);
    }

    private void breakProcessBox(Canvas canvas, int spaceRemaining) {
        double bestHeight = spaceRemaining - 24;
        double processHeight = processLayout.getHeight();
        double percentHeight = bestHeight/processHeight;
        Spanned processString = makeItSpan(lesson.getField("process"));
        String htmlProcessString = HTMLConverter.saveToHtml(processString);
        Pair<StaticLayout, StaticLayout> splitLayouts = splitProcessString(bestHeight, processHeight, htmlProcessString);
        if (splitLayouts.first != null) {
            processLayout = splitLayouts.first;
            drawProcessBox(canvas);
        }
        if (splitLayouts.second != null) {
            extraProcessLayout = splitLayouts.second;
            hasExtraProcess = true;
        } else {
            hasExtraProcess = false;
        }
    }

    private void drawExtraProcessBox(Canvas canvas) {
        if (extraProcessLayout != null) {
            StaticLayout thirdPageLayout = null;
            if (extraProcessLayout.getHeight() > printHeight - 24) {
                Spanned extraText = (Spanned) extraProcessLayout.getText();
                Pair<StaticLayout, StaticLayout> splitLayouts = splitProcessString(printHeight - 24, extraProcessLayout.getHeight(), HTMLConverter.saveToHtml(extraText));
                extraProcessLayout = splitLayouts.first;
                thirdPageLayout = splitLayouts.second;
            }
            canvas.translate(0, 8);
            int totalHeight = 8;
            processLabel.draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(100, 0);
            extraProcessLayout.draw(canvas);
            if (processLabel.getHeight() > extraProcessLayout.getHeight()) {
                canvas.translate(-100, processLabel.getHeight() + 8);
                totalHeight += processLabel.getHeight() + 8;
            } else {
                canvas.translate(-100, extraProcessLayout.getHeight() + 8);
                totalHeight += extraProcessLayout.getHeight() + 8;
            }
            canvas.translate(-8, -totalHeight);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, printWidth + 16, totalHeight, boxPaint);
            canvas.translate(8, totalHeight + 8);
            if (thirdPageLayout != null) {
                extraProcessLayout = thirdPageLayout;
                hasExtraProcess = true;
            } else {
                hasExtraProcess = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawAssessmentBox(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.translate(0, 8);
        int totalHeight = 8;
        assessmentLabel.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(100, 0);
        assessmentLayout.draw(canvas);
        if (assessmentLabel.getHeight() > assessmentLayout.getHeight()) {
            canvas.translate(-100, assessmentLabel.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += assessmentLabel.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(-100, assessmentLayout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += assessmentLayout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        canvas.translate(-8, -totalHeight);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, printWidth + 16, totalHeight, boxPaint);
        canvas.translate(8, totalHeight + 8);
    }

    private void drawCommentBox(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.translate(0, 8);
        int totalHeight = 8;
        commentLabel.draw(canvas);
        canvas.translate(100, 0);
        commentLayout.draw(canvas);
        if (commentLabel.getHeight() > commentLayout.getHeight()) {
            canvas.translate(-100, commentLabel.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += commentLabel.getHeight() + 8;
        } else {
            canvas.translate(-100, commentLayout.getHeight() + 8);
            totalHeight += commentLayout.getHeight() + 8;
        }
        canvas.translate(-8, -totalHeight);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, printWidth + 16, totalHeight, boxPaint);
        canvas.translate(8, totalHeight + 8);
    }

    private Pair<StaticLayout, StaticLayout> splitProcessString(double remainingSpace, double fullHeight, String htmlString) {
        StaticLayout firstLayout;
        StaticLayout secondLayout;
        double percentHeight = remainingSpace/fullHeight;
        int characterLength = htmlString.length();
        Double split = characterLength * percentHeight;
        int findBreak = htmlString.lastIndexOf("<br>", split.intValue());
        int findParagraphEnd = htmlString.lastIndexOf("</p>", split.intValue());
        int findGoodSpot = -1;
        int offSet = 3;
        if (findBreak > findParagraphEnd) {
            findGoodSpot = findBreak;
        } else {
            findGoodSpot = findParagraphEnd;
            offSet = 4;
        }
        if (findGoodSpot > characterLength) {
            firstLayout = new StaticLayout(HTMLConverter.makeItSpan(htmlString), textPaint, printWidth - 124, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, false);
            secondLayout = null;
            return Pair.create(firstLayout, secondLayout);
        } else if (findGoodSpot < 0) {
            secondLayout = new StaticLayout(HTMLConverter.makeItSpan(htmlString), textPaint, printWidth - 124, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, false);
            firstLayout = null;
            return Pair.create(firstLayout, secondLayout);
        } else {
            String firstHalf = htmlString.substring(0, findGoodSpot);
            String secondHalf = htmlString.substring(findGoodSpot + offSet);
            Spanned firstHalfSpanned = HTMLConverter.makeItSpan(firstHalf);
            Spanned secondHalfSpanned = HTMLConverter.makeItSpan(secondHalf);
            firstLayout = new StaticLayout(firstHalfSpanned, textPaint, printWidth - 124, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, false);
            secondLayout = new StaticLayout(secondHalfSpanned, textPaint, printWidth - 124, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, false);
            return Pair.create(firstLayout, secondLayout);
        }
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: Sometimes I get the following message on the device after the attempt: "Unfortunately, Print Spooler has Stopped".

Comment: Did you check the Print spooler crash message from the logs? Did you check the pdf file you create in the destination and does it seem valid?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my `while` loop and the `startIndex` counter. `onWrite` is called twice - first to create the preview, then again to save/print. On the second run, `startIndex` was already out of bounds, and thus nothing was printed. Simple solution: reset `startIndex` inside `onWrite`.

Answer (score 1):

After years of using the Android Chrome Settings-Share-Print it then became inoperative because in every attempt it got stuck on continually spooling in the Print Preview mode.  It would not print a PDF & I couldn't find a solution on the internet.

Using Play Store I was able to remedy this myself by Disabling the Android Accessibility Suite, then resetting it to Factory Version, and then going back to Play Store and updating it.  Worth remembering and I hope that it works for you too if you ever need it !